# getting attempt to re-open an already-closed object

Tags: android, android-sqlite

while inserting into table am getting attempt to re-open an already-closed object exception

```
   public class UploadImagesToServer {

    static ImgeURLdb imgURLdb;
    static  Context mContext;
    public static void postImage(String ImageLink, String imageName, Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        imgURLdb = new ImgeURLdb(mContext);
        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("file",new File(ImageLink));
            Log.i("imageName","Sending Image"+ImageLink);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Constants.MediaUpload, jsonObject, future, future);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(request);

        try {
            JSONObject response = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// Blocks for at most 10 seconds.
            String imageURL = response.getString("");
            addImagetoDB(imageName,imageURL);
            Log.i("imageName","getting URL"+imageURL+"");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Exception handling
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // Exception handling
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

            //addImagetoDB(imageName,"imageURL");

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    private static void addImagetoDB(String imageName, String imageURL) {

        imgURLdb.addImageURL(imageName,imageURL);


    }
}
```

above code is adding url to db

```
 public void addImageURL(String imageName, String imageURL){

    DbHelper mDBhelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String query = "Select id from "+DbHelper.IMAGE_URL+" where "+DbHelper.IMAGE_NAME + "=?";
    String[] args = new String[1];
    args[0] = imageName;

    Cursor myCursur = mDBhelper.myquery(query,args);

    if (myCursur != null && myCursur.getCount() > 0) {
        myCursur.moveToPosition(-1);
        while (myCursur.moveToNext()) {
            values.put(DbHelper.IMAGE_URL,imageURL);
            sqlDB.insert(DbHelper.IMAGE_URL, null, values);

        }
        myCursur.close();

    } else
    {
        Log.e("tag", "Cursor is zero");

    }

    mDBhelper.close();
    sqlDB.close();

}
```

this is the method which am adding image url to db. While adding am getting attempt to re-open an already-closed object exception

Comment: Please post code of DbHelper class, there is some issue. most probably in getWritableDatabase() method or myquery() method.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the implementation of  your "myquery()" method in DbHelper, but you're probably closing the cursor inside that method, then you return it. If you don't close the cursor there, it should be fine.